# How to validate variables from command line parameters in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which I execute with:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/staging/ myPlaybook.yml  -e "srv_mode=restart"
```

The variable `srv_mode` is used in a play. Now I only want to allow "restart" and "start" as its values.

Is there a possibility to evaluate the content of `srv_mode` at first and to end gracefully with a nice warning in case the value is not supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`assert` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/assert_module.html), optimally in a separate play at the top of your playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  pre_tasks:
    - assert:
        that: srv_mode in ['start', 'restart']
```

Comment: I'd advice to make separate play for that with `localhost` only and `gather_facts: no` to prevent possible host loop and fact gathering process.

Comment: "*prevent host loop*"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: If there's tens of hosts in OP's play, the execution flow will be prepared for every host. And `assert` (without run_once) will be executed that many times.